# Ошибка "Not an array" в Google charts

Tags: javascript, json, google-chart

```
 function drawChart() {
 var data= result;

    var datas = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
     var options = {
      title: 'Показники',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    }
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(datas, options);
  }
```

Консоль выводит ошибку "Not an array". 
А сервер отдает такие данные:

```
{"cols":{"\u0413\u0431\u0442\u0422":"string","\u0312\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0437\u043d\u0438\u043a":"number"},"rows":[["2016-01-01","5\u0002312"],["2016-02-01","4\u00a0416"],["2016-03-01","4\u00a0430"],["2016-04-01","4\u00a0043"],["2016-05-01","3\u00a0500"],["2016-06-01","3263"],["2016-07-01","2736"],["2016-08-01","2890"]]}
```

JSON.parse не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер отдает правильные данные, не нужно их переводить
Вместо этого: `var datas = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);`
Нужно это: `var datas = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);`